# Displaying a library on a different site (same collection) in SP2013

Tags: web-part, document-library, site-collection, xslt-list-view-web-part, cross-site

On my root site, I have a Document Library which contains a lot of important documents. For this Library, on its owning site I can create a webpart which views the folders and items in a nice manner.

I want to display the library from the root site in a similar (or the same) manner on a subsite of the root site. I have tried two solutions that only worked partially:

1. On the site where I want to view the library, I created a Page Viewer Webpart with its url set to [dialogview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414166%28v=office.14%29.aspx). This created a good looking view of the items in the library, but it is not possible to open folders or add/remove items...
2. [I created the list view webpart on the site where the library is, downloaded the webpart, edited its code to reference correct IDs and uploaded on the subsite](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.no/2009/03/sharepoint-one-library-multiple-sites.html). Like the first solutions, this gave a beatiful view of the folders and items at the top of the Library, but also an inability to navigate.

Is there a way to achieve what I desire? At least an easy way to copy over the Document Library to the subsite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by using page view webpart on the document library with "?IsDlg=1" added to the url arguments:

/File Archive/Forms/AllItems.aspx?IsDlg=1