# Issue Tracking app group specific columns

Tags: 2013, app, issue-tracking

In SharePoint I am working on an Issue Tracking app (the built in one).

1. I would like to have the app displayed on the homepage for everyone at the company to use.
2. Then have it also appear on our IT subsite with more information (that all staff cannot view).

That way we can write down the steps and fixes as the pertain to the help tickets submitted by other staff on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Display Issue tracking App on Homepage-

1. Goto Homepage.
2. Click on Page from ribbon and Edit Page.
3. Click on Add Web Part in the section where you would like to show Issue Tracking App.
4. Select Issue Tracking App from Ribbon.
5. Click Add.

This would add Issue Tracking App in your homepage. You can change its view by editing this web part.

In case, you want to show it on another site try this- [Displaying a library on a different site (same collection) in SP2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74849/displaying-a-library-on-a-different-site-same-collection-in-sp2013)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, but that is not what I am asking..I know how to add the app to the homepage. What I want is to have the IT dept to have a way to add technical steps to the Issue tracker but not have all staff see those (for obvious reasons..)